# Using IIS 7.5 with Tomcat and ARR to re-write URL

Tags: apache, iis, tomcat

I've tried searching but can't seem to get the answer I need.

I have some webservices managed by IIS. However, we need to host a web application run on Tomcat on the same server. The solution it seems, is to create a Server Farm in IIS, and this works for the most part.

The url we normally use to access the app run on Tomcat is localhost:8080.
By setting up the server farm in IIS, I've managed to get http://localhost to redirect to the same app. However, this creates a conflict with another app, so I want a custom path like http://localhost/Webapp/ to redirect there. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your app on tomcat is the so called root application. This is the application that resides under the server root url.

You need to get the application run on tomcat under the url http://localhost:8080/Webapp. To achieve this, simply install the application under the context Webapp. How to do this depends on how your application is installed. If it is a folder inside tomcats webapp folder, simply rename this folder. If it is defined by an context definition (ROOT.xml) inside the tomcats conf folder, rename this context definition to Webapp.xml.